# Making first mobile Safari tap a 'clickable action'

Tags: ios, angularjs, mobile-safari

I have seen variations on the theme, but no clear answer.  Basically I want an AngularJS Directive that registers a click and inserts extra content into a page, and then scrolls down a bit to make the new content visible.  Here is the HTML

```
    <li class="btn btn-default" ng-show="resto.link !== 'none'">
        <p scroll-down onclick="void(0)">
            Full review 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right"></span>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-bind-html="fullReview">
    </div>
</div>
```

The onlick part is an [Apple suggestion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6), that seems not to work.
And then I have:

```
.directive 'scrollDown', () ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, $elm, attrs) ->
        $elm.on 'click', (e) ->
            e.preventDefault()
            scope.getFullReview () ->
                console.log "Scrolling'
                $("body").animate
                    scrollTop: $elm.offset().top - 100
                ,   "slow"
```

getFullReview() updates the model after an AJAX call, and then runs the callback.

This works fine in Chrome but not on the iOS simulator - basically a first tap makes the page move (but without triggering the console log - I think this is the URL bar regrowing) and a second is needed to trigger the Directive's link function.  I have also installed fastclick as that was mentioned in some posts, but it did not help.

Need ideas :-)  (Even some code that would tell me what event is being triggered by safari)

Answer (score 0):

OK, Wow, I do not understand why, but the html above was the last markup on the page, so all of this was happening at the bottom of the screen.  When I added some extra margin to the `<ul>` element, everything started working perfectly!!  Bug in Safari?